# Play a game on two ps4s

Tags: ps4

My brother got a ps4,i brought a game and installed on his, but I'm going to buy a ps4 can I install that game on mine or will I have to buy the game again.

Comment: If you bought it on his account, then you will have to download it on your PS4 from his account, but you will not be able to play unless you make that *his* primary PS4 rather than yours, which I'm sure is not what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

For downloaded games they only work on the primary PS4 of the account who bought it.

For disc games it works on any PS4 where the disc is inserted.

Which makes perfect sense, otherwise somebody can borrow his game to everyone he knows so they would get it for free.

Comment: Yeahh I brought it from game so the disc, I had my own account of his ps4 so if I put my own on

Comment: Psn on it should work right?

Comment: Yes, PSN and disc game are unrelated as long as the game doesn't have a network multiplayer component. If you have PS+, it will also be easier for you to get back your save file. Without, you can still use a USB stick.